# Filter a list view using URL parameters

Tags: development, list, filter

I would like to dynamically construct a couple of URLs for our SharePoint users to filter down a rather large list view we have. Rather than create a bunch of different custom views, I was wondering if there is a way to just pass some URL arguments to the AllItems.aspx page and have the filter be applied during page load.

I envision maybe create a text box where they can type a question like "DocumentID" and give it a value of "12345" - then have javascript construct an appropriate URL like:

```
http://server/site/Lists/Links/AllItems.aspx?MyFilter=DocumentID:12345
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you filter manually, you'll see that the URL changes, e.g. to something like

http://server/site/Lists/Links/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=DocumentID&FilterValue1=650

So if you pass the parameters FilterField1 and FilterValue1 accordingly, it should work.

Comment: This worked like a charm - exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: it's don't work when you have to filter multiples lists

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend customizing a regular SharePoint view page in this way.  You could create another page though outside of the list or library and put a dataview on there that uses the URL input property.

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @frenchone, Mike is saying that it is not best practice to edit pages in the `/Lists/MyList/` directory of a site. Instead, create a page in the Site Pages or Pages libraries and add a List View Web part of the desired list. From there you can add whatever you want to the page safely.

Comment: That's more clear. But: OP does not edit pages he filters existing list using url. I guess OP want a dynamic filter, this can't be done using LVWP (or can it ?) And if this can be done, how would it be different (/better) from directly filtering through url filter ?

Answer (score 1):

To use the query string parameters as filters you can use the Query String Filter Web Part and connect to a List View Web Part on a Web Part page.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Filter Web Parts require an Enterprise license.

Comment: Query String Filter Web Part definitely the way to go (if available to you).

Answer (score 1):

Hi this was a useful post ( I know it is old but I found it!), but I ran into problems with my URL and characters that the string builder didn't like - the 'you cant have [%%]' error message

My link was this kind of thing:

`http://foobar/Lists/ECR%20System%20Build/AllItems.aspx?View={by%20ECR%20status}#InplviewHashf777aa1d-dde8-4d51-b8d1-18b514c226f9=FilterField1%3DECR%255Fx0020%255FID-FilterValue1%3D417`  (where 417 was the ID in my lookup list)

I already had a lot of rows and wanted to fix them up retrospectively.  The concatenation idea didn't seem to work for me.

so I did this (after copying a filtered view URL that worked and adapting it)

I made a string type workflow variable:

```
then set variable systemslink to    http://collaborate/sites/trustwide/openriocomm/Lists/ECR System Build/AllItems.aspx?View=All Items#InplviewHashf777aa1d-dde8-4d51-b8d1-18b514c226f9=FilterField1=ECR%255Fx0020%255FID-FilterValue1=[%Current Item:ID%], my hyperlink label
```

then I copied that variable value into my destination hyperlink type column `Systems view`:

.. `then set Systems view to Variable:systemslink`

and this worked beautifully, when added to my 'on creation' workflow.

to fix up the others I used an MS access update query, where the syntax is quite different:

```
UPDATE [ECR Tracker] SET [ECR Tracker].[Systems view] = "See System Build(s)#http://foobar/Lists/ECR%20System%20Build/AllItems.aspx?View={by%20ECR%20status}#InplviewHashf777aa1d-dde8-4d51-b8d1-18b514c226f9=FilterField1%3DECR%255Fx0020%255FID-FilterValue1%3D" & [ID] & "#";
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a post i wrote to demonstrate how we can filter a SharePoint list view web part with JavaScript.

Uses the same concept as suggested by Modery

http://rahul-vartak.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-2007-filtering-list-view-web.html

Hope this is useful..:)