# Filter a page's web-parts via URL

Tags: 2010, web-part, filter

I made a page with multiple web-parts each a different list but contain a similar column. I would like to filter the web-parts via url. Something like:

https://OurOrginizationSite.org/sites/TheSiteInRefrence/SitePages/Review.aspx?FilterColumn1=Category&FilterValue1=Blue%20Team

https://OurOrginizationSite.org/sites/TheSiteInRefrence/SitePages/Review.aspx?FilterColumn1=Category&FilterValue1=Red%20Team

Also would that column have to be visible? I would like to filter by a column that is not displayed in the web-part but is in fact in the list itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this post[1] before asking my question but wasn't able to get it to work and thought it might not work with pages with multiple web-parts. Turns out I was wrong and it does work.

[1][Filter a list view using URL parameters](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/filter-a-list-view-using-url-parameters)