# Is there a way to use URL to pass filters or search terms to display a page with certain results?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a bunch of pdfs that I plan to have links to display certain information from a bunch of lists I am using as a mini database in sharepoint. However, but in order for the hyperlinks in the pdfs to work in a reasonably structured manner, I am attempting to find a way that I can do some manipulation to a certain filter on a list or to open a library with a particular search term in the "find a file" search box. Is there a way I can do that?

If document library with metadata is not the way, or that lists are not the way, I can consider using just an excel file uploaded if there is a way to execute certain office 365 filtering in excel online through URL manipulation. I can do some scripting if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters can be passed in lists by adding

```
?&FilterField1=ID&FilterValue=12345
```

at the end of the url of allitems.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for query string (URL) filters. They let you specify a particular query string parameter that can be used to filter items in a web part.

So essentially you need to pass on a particular value in a query string parameter and wire up the query string filter web part to pass on that parameter as a filter value to your respective document library web part.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to do. But I wanted to have the ability to pass two items and it is not cooperating. What I am doing is similar to this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/filter-a-list-view-using-url-parametershttp://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/filter-a-list-view-using-url-parameters

Comment: I think I solved it, the problem was with spaces and after I started the table from scratch and named the column without spaces, it worked fine.