# Filtering list view web part through URL only works once

Tags: 2013, list-view

I created a page with a list view web part. I want to have links to this page and have it filter based on a parameter passed through the URL. Using [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/filter-a-list-view-using-url-parameters) I built the URL so it looks like this: http://site/Pages/CustomPage.aspx?FilterField1=Color&FilterValue1=Red

It works fine just to display the information but it doesn't work if I try to further filter on color. The URL keeps the initial color. Is there a better way to do this?