# Querystring filter on documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, query-string

I have a list of documents who have a property (Related document ID) that I want to filter via query string

Example:

```
site.com/document?PolicyID=1
```

should view only documents who have the related ID = 1

I was thinking of using a Highlighted Content web part with a custom CAML query.

This is what I have so far:

```
<View>
<Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Related_x0020_Document_x003a_ID'/>
<Value Type='Text'>{QueryString:PolicyID}</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

Can anyone with a basic understanding explain how it works?

I just want CAML to accept a query string on Sharepoint: https://i.stack.imgur.com/riSdI.png

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but you don't necessarily need to pass any values to a custom CAML query in order to use query params for filtering.  SharePoint already has a built-in mechanism for doing this when looking at list views: `FilterField` and `FilterValue`.

So for instance, in your case you could apply the filtering you want by constructing a URL like:

```
https://your.sharepoint.site/lists/your-doc-library/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=PolicyID&FilterValue1=1
```

Notice that there's a `1` tacked on the end of those params: `FilterField1` and `FilterValue1`.  So that also means you can apply multiple filters by using `FilterField2`/`FilterValue2`, etc.

There's another similar question and answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/3692/8992).

Comment: Thank you Dylan. I can filter the original document library using this method but I want this to apply to a web part (I have tried 'Highlighted Content' and 'Document Library' web parts. I am doing site.com/Page.aspx?FilterField1=Related_x0020_Document_x003a_ID&FilterValue1=1&FilterType1=Lookup

Answer (score 0):

You could just concatenate it into the string. Hope it helps you:

```
Query.ViewXml ="<View>
<Query>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Related_x0020_Document_x003a_ID'/>
<Value Type='Text'>" + yourParameter + " </Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
</View>"
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, not sure how I can concatenate my paramter through Sharepoint though, take a look at this image: https://i.imgur.com/077K0Mp.png

Comment: What's the policy ID? Where you define it? In the url?

Comment: Policy ID is a property on the column I created, which is a look up to the document in another collection that it links to e.g. 'Finance Document' will have a linked 'Expenses Document' whose PolicyID is the same ID as Finance document